# Beating (possibly) caused by different sampling frequencies?

Tags: signal-processing

So I plugged a signal generator at 0.06 V peak to peak and frequency 1 Hz into my apparatus. 
The signal is processed in two steps:
1) signal fed to a first computer, which outputs stuff at sampling freqency 10 Hz,
2) the output from the first computer is fed to a second machine (sampling frequency 16 Hz), and then plotted.

This is what I see:

[image]

The peak to peak voltage is twice the one I selected but that might be caused by a load resistance different from the one that the signal generator is expecting (but if you can explain this quantitatively I would be extremely grateful).

Why is there beating? Could it be due to the difference in sampling frequencies?

Thanks.

Comment: Does computer 1 send an analog signal to computer 2?  I'd recommend as a first step sending your 1Hz from the function generator directly into computer 2, and generating the same graph.  Debugging is a step-at-a-time process, and this will confirm that everything with computer 2 is OK.

Comment: Ah, that I don't know. I mean I don't know if it's digital or analogue... would one of the two cause beating? I am not an engineer, so I don't really know what's going on... sorry

Comment: I don't know if one is better than the other, but just trying to get a better grip on the situation.  You could be looking at just some indexing problem on an array, for all I know.

Comment: I understand why there are constant values, since the second computer is sampling faster than the other one, so it sees the same values sometimes

Comment: Aah, I thought we were looking at 1 cycle.

Comment: It looks like your computer 1 is outputting at something less than 10Hz.  I count less than 40 transitions in 5 seconds.

Comment: Let me just add, the amplitude of the beating increases with increasing frequency set on the signal generator

Comment: If you don't understand your apparatus -- and therefore can't describe it to us -- how do you expect us to figure out what might be going wrong with it? Where did you get the apparatus? Who set it up for you? Have you asked that person these questions?

Comment: Dear Dave, sorry if my question seemed to hard to answer and if it is lacking some key information. I was hoping someone might have had the same problem in the past and was able to recognise a trend. You are welcome to ignore it

Comment: You say you have things sampling at 10 Hz and 16 Hz, but there aren't nearly that many samples in the graph. I count 38 samples in the first 5s period, meaning a sample rate of about 38/5=7.6. Something doesn't add up.

Comment: there are multiple points on the flat lines, I checked on matlab with the cursors and it all adds up

Comment: Yup,@Harold, if you want it to look better, you need to sample faster at computer 1, or use slower input signals.  This is just basic sampling (see my answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably just a manifestation of your actual sample rate and your input wave not sharing a common divisor.

Here's a quick Matlab example, with a sample rate of 8Hz and a frequency of 0.92.

```
>> time=[0:50]/8;
>> f=0.92;
>> out=sin(2*pi*f*time);
>> plot(time, out);
```

[image]

It's not as dramatic as your example, but given time, and your funny resampling, I'm sure I can come up with something as dramatic.

Meeting Nyquist sampling criteria does not mean that simply plotting the data will yield perfect reconstruction-- it just means that it's possible to mathematically reconstruct the original signal.  Watch what happens when I up my input signal!!

```
>> f=2.3;
>> out=sin(2*pi*f*time);
>> plot(time, out,'-*')
```

[image]

At 2.3 Hertz, I'm sampling (8Hz) at more than three times the input freq, but the result still looks messy.

Resampling will only make things messier (but that's a hair much to spend time to simulate here, as Matlab resampling commands will upsample by interpolation, so doing it the way you're doing it is more complex)

Comment: OK, actually going higher than sampling_frequency/2 was another thing I was unsure about. I still see a sine wave for frequencies way over Nyquist... but the amplitude changes. Is that normal? I was expecting aliasing to destroy the original signal.

Comment: Yes, you will still see a sin wave when you go above nyquist on the input, it will just be lower frequency than what's really there -- and that's ALIASING, by definition.  I see from your conversation above that you have Matlab.  Do these simulations to convince yourself.

Comment: Oh yes it is indeed at a lower frequency, thanks, didn't notice that

Answer (score 0):

> there are multiple points on the flat lines

Exactly.  The non-trivial relationship between the two sampling rates means that sometimes the second (16 sps) sampler sees the first (10 sps) sampler's sample twice, and sometimes it sees it only once.

If you want to avoid this, you need a reconstruction filter after the first sampler, to remove the artifacts of the sample rate from its output.  Typically this would take the form of an analog (or much higher sample rate digital) lowpass filter with a cutoff below half of the sampling rate of this stage.  Further, you need to treat each output from the low rate sampler into this filter as an **impulse** rather than as a **step**.

Comment: Yes, that I understand. It's beating that I don't get. The beating amplitude and frequency seem to stay the same (from other plots), although he amplitude increases with increasing frequency, so I thought there was sth more "peculiar" going on.
But then again, beating disappears at low frequencies (approx 0.1 Hz) so it might be still related to the diff sampling freqeucnies

Comment: What is the input frequency?

Comment: It's 1 Hz set on the signal generator

Comment: If real-time isn't a need, one interesting approach for reconstruction would be to take the FFT, and insert zero values in between each point.  For example, adding four zeroes in between each point would mean upping the effective sampling rate by a factor of five.  Then take the IFFT and spit that back out, and then resample.

Comment: Yes, but it's simpler to use an FIR filter - specifically, you use a trivial form of a polyphase FIR where only low rate worth of the high rate inputs are nonzero and thus need evaluating.  Or if your low rate is only a small fraction of your high rate (or you feel like building a pre-compensating filter) you can use a CIC.

Comment: @Harold - for 1 Hz input and 10 sps, the output of the first sampler would be a reasonable (if stairstep) representation of the input.  You will see that the peak level varies slightly if the sampler is not a perfect multiple of the input frequency.  But most of what you are seeing is the relationship between the first sampler and the second.